# npm init -y not working in windows (VScode error)

Tags: javascript, npm, visual-studio-code

C:\Users\User\Desktop\WEB DEV>npm init -y
npm ERR! Invalid name: "WEB DEV"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-05T13_55_29_054Z-debug.log

C:\Users\User\Desktop\WEB DEV>

Comment: why you dont jsut write `npm init`

Comment: Rename the `WEB DEV` folder as `WEB-DEV` (i.e. no space character) and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You're name has a **space** which is not `URL Safe`

See at the rules of naming a package.json here

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json